# Php form checked when the checkbox value in array mysql query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have and value in my database. It's call `type`

I have 2 checkbox in my html form.

```
<input name="barea[]" type="checkbox" id="barea[]" value="1" {$cbvar}/>Normal 
<input name="barea[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="barea[]" {$cbvar}/>Gold
```

And I store data as code below:

```
$checkboxvar = implode(',', $_GET['barea']);
```

So my table data like:

```
+-------+-----------+
| ID    | type      |
+-------+-----------+
| 1     | 1         |
| 2     | 1,2       |
| 3     | 2         |
| 4     | 1,2       |
| 5     | 1,2       |
| 6     | 1         |
+-------------------+
```

When user edit this data, how to `checked` the checkbox when the `barea[] value` exist `in_array` in the `mysql_query`?

I try the below coding, in my php file:

```
$checkbox = explode(',',$row['type']);
if (in_array($_GET['barea'],$checkbox)){
    $cbvar = "checked=\"checked\"";
}else{
    $cbvar = '';
}
```

In my html

```
<input name="barea[]" type="checkbox" id="barea[]" value="1" {$cbvar}/>Normal 
<input name="barea[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="barea[]" {$cbvar}/>Gold
```

But it can't work, i think maybe the problem is on `if (in_array($_GET['barea'],$checkbox)){`.

so how to improve my coding, or any other good coding suggestion? thank you.

Comment: What value are you getting in ``$_GET['barea']`` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

=>Try this Code I hope it's useful.

// html page..

```
<label>Select State</label><br>
<?php 
$allgroup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  state");
$flag=false;
while($state_list = mysql_fetch_array($allgroup))
{
   $parr=explode(',',$er['state_id']);
   $size = sizeof($parr);
   for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++) { 
     if($parr[$i]==$state_list['id']) {                              
        $flag=true;
     } 
   }    

  if($flag==true) {
    ?>
    <input  type='checkbox' name='state[]' style="margin-left:5px;" value="<?php echo $state_list['id']; ?>" checked  > <?php echo $state_list['name']; ?> <br>
    <?php
    $flag=false;
  } else { 
    ?>
    <input  type='checkbox' name='state[]' style="margin-left:5px;" value="<?php echo $state_list['id']; ?>"     > <?php echo $state_list['name']; ?> <br>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

// php  code ..

```
<?php
$states="";
$i=0;
foreach( $_POST['state'] as $selected) {
   echo sizeof($_POST['state']);
   if($i==sizeof($_POST['state'])-1) {
       $states = $states.$selected;
   } else {
     $states = $states.$selected.",";
   }
   $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to sanitize `$_POST`, it is good coding practice to not access the POST superglobal directly.

+1 for initializing your variables before using them :)