# How to retrieve checkbox value from database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

My question is how to retrieve a checkbox value from the database in PHP. The below code is not working.

```
<td>Hobby</td>
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT hobby FROM simple WHERE id = id"); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $focus = explode(",", $row['hobby']);
?>    
<td>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="hobby[]"  value="Cricket"  size="17"   <?php if(in_array("Cricket",$hobby)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >Cricket
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Music" size="17" <?php if(in_array("Music",$hobby)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >Music
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Reading"   size="17" <?php if(in_array("Reading",$hobby)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >Reading
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Study" size="17" <?php if(in_array("Study",$hobby)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> >Study</td>
<?php
   }
?>
</tr>
```

Comment: Note that you'll fetch all datasets when using condition `WHERE id = id` in your SQL statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491898/php-form-checked-when-the-checkbox-value-in-array-mysql-query/34492079#34492079

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the statement,

```
$focus=explode(",",$row['hobby']);
```

To:

```
$hobby=explode(",",$row['hobby']);
```

Also, You can minimize your code with the use of ternary operators instead of if else like:

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox"  name="hobby[]"  value="Cricket"  size="17" <?php echo (in_array("Cricket",$hobby)) ? 'checked="checked" : '';?>>Cricket
  <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Music" size="17" <?php echo (in_array("Music",$hobby)) ? 'checked="checked" : '';?>>Music
  <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Reading"   size="17" <?php echo (in_array("Reading",$hobby)) ? 'checked="checked" : '';?>>Reading
</td>
```

Also, @mapek suggested, your SQL will fetch all records.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT hobby FROM simple WHERE id = id");
```

As `id` will always be equal to `id`.

You should change it to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT hobby FROM simple WHERE id = '$id'");
```

**Another version to minimize this code with arrays:**

```
<td>
<?php
$hobbies = array('Cricket', 'Music', 'Reading');
if (! empty($hobbies)) {
  foreach ($hobbies as $myHobby) {
    $checked = (in_array($myHobby, $hobby)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="<?php echo $myHobby;?>" size="17" <?php echo $checked;?>><?php echo $myHobby;?>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this : many changes required

```
<td>Hobby</td>
    <?php
        $id= 1; // your input id value
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT hobby FROM simple WHERE id = $id"); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
        $hobby=explode(",",$row['hobby']);

    ?>    
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="hobby[]"  value="Cricket"  size="17"   <?php if(in_array("Cricket",$hobby)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> >Cricket
         <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Music" size="17" <?php if(in_array("Music",$hobby)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> >Music
         <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Reading"   size="17" <?php if(in_array("Reading",$hobby))  echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> >Reading
         <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Study" size="17" <?php if(in_array("Study",$hobby))  echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> >Study</td>
       <?php
       }
       ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: please show me output for $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT hobby FROM simple");

Comment: my simply code<td>Hobby</td>
   
        
    <td><input type="checkbox"  name="hobby[]"  value="Cricket" >Cricket
         <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Music" >Music
         <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Reading">Reading
         <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]"  value="Study" >Study</td>
     
</tr>

Comment: are you getting output for mysqli_query($con,"SELECT hobby FROM simple"); ? what is it ?

Comment: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Comment: then something wrong with connection. try mysqli_query("SELECT hobby FROM simple");. pls tell me its output ?

Comment: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: what is $con value ?

Comment: connection is correct & form data is upload in table but problem is there if i   am edit data then not show checkbox tick mark

Comment: $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'vrajesh123');
if (!$con) {
   die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: you are using mysql or mysqli ?

Comment: here you have mentioned mysql_connect() and used mysqli_query(); use mysql_query instead. try edited answer.

Comment: if used mysqli in connection form display error  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Comment: wherever you have used mysqli change to mysql

Comment: okk change  & in query i am remove $con then no error is display but no tick mark show

Comment: now what is the output for mysql_query("SELECT hobby FROM simple")

Comment: do one thing post the whole code for edit in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Change variable name in

`<?php if(in_array("Cricket",$hobby)) { ?>`

from `$hobby` to `$focus`

Comment: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = explode(",",$result['hobbies']);
<input type="checkbox" name ="hobbies[]" value ="reading" <?php if(in_array("reading",$newArray)){ echo "checked";} ?>
<input type="checkbox" name ="hobbies[]" value = "games" <?php if(in_array("games",$newArray)){ echo "checked";}?>>`
<input type="checkbox" name ="hobbies[]" value = "coding"  <?php if(in_array("coding",$newArray)){ echo "checked";} ?>
```

Comment: Not upload your code only, describe your problem to get a answer quickly.